# Significant location change

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have tried the significant location change in the latest iOS 8 update but the `Core Location` manager method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

is never called.

When using method `startUpdatingLocation` the method above is called.

Everything worked in iOS 7 for the app. I need to update to iOS 8.

Share your experience.

Comment: Im also facing this issue. Were you able to find the reason significant location update not working on iOS 8

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you're not following the instructions here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Events are going to be accumulated while your app is not running. Your app launches and must immediately create a location manager and start significant location updates all over again in order to receive that accumulated information.

Comment: Deprecated in iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating to iOS 8 be sure to make the changes in the property list (.plist) file: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and/or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDecription : http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/getting-gps-location-using-core-location-in-ios-8-vs-ios-7/